# Are the perfect groups linearly primitive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

A finite group $G$ is *perfect* if $G = G^{(1)} := \langle [G,G] \rangle$, or equivalently, if any $1$-dimensional complex representation is trivial.

A finite group $G$ is [linearly primitive](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_primitive_group) if it has a faithful complex irreducible representation.

*Question:* Are the perfect finite groups linearly primitive?

*Remark*: the finite simple groups are perfect and linearly primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Any linearly primitive group must have [cyclic center](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Cyclic-center_group) by [Schur's lemma](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_primitive_implies_cyclic-center), but there's no reason a perfect group should have this property. I think that, for example, the [universal central extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_multiplier#Relation_to_central_extensions) of $A_5 \times A_5$ is perfect but has center $C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: More precisely $G = {\rm SL}(2,5) \times {\rm SL}(2,5)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Is there a counterexample which is not a (semi-)direct product?

Comment: The perfect group number 4 of order 3840 (which is called A5 2^4 E ( 2^1 x N 2^1 in the  book of Holt/Plesken)  has a centre of type $C_2\times C_2$ but cannot be written as a semidirect product of any proper subgroups. (This is the smallest example.)